# React.js Failed to compile: unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mern

everyone. I keep getting this error, and I don't know whats wrong:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYyM6.jpg)

It says that there is an unexpected token and that there has to be a comma somewhere.

Can somebody tell me, whats wrong with my code?
Here it is.. the render-part is down below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class CreateOberbegriff extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeOberbegriff = this.onChangeOberbegriff.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      oberbegriff: ''
    }
  }

  onChangeOberbegriff(e) {
    this.setState({
      oberbegriff: e.target.value
    })
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const oberbegriff = {
      oberbegriff: this.state.oberbegriff
    }

    console.log(oberbegriff);

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/oberbegriffe/add', oberbegriff
      .then(res => console.log(res.data)),

    this.setState({
      oberbegriff: ''
    })
  ,

  render()
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Create New Oberbegriff</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>oberbegriff: </label>
            <input  type="text"
                required
                className="form-control"
                value={this.state.oberbegriff}
                onChange={this.onChangeOberbegriff}
                />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create Oberbegriff" className="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  ),
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the error message?

Comment: Sorry, now its there. Just click on the "Error message"! :) Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a comma above render :

```
  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/oberbegriffe/add', oberbegriff
      .then(res => console.log(res.data)),

    this.setState({
      oberbegriff: ''
    })
  , // HERE IS YOUR COMMA
  render()
    return (
      <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem:

```
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/oberbegriffe/add', oberbegriff
      .then(res => console.log(res.data)),
```

You didn`t close the post function and also have a comma at the end, which should be a semicolon:

```
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/oberbegriffe/add', oberbegriff)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data));
```

It should work like this. If not, just write another comment.

The whole file should look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class CreateOberbegriff extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeOberbegriff = this.onChangeOberbegriff.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      oberbegriff: ''
    }
  }

  onChangeOberbegriff(e) {
    this.setState({
      oberbegriff: e.target.value
    })
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const oberbegriff = {
      oberbegriff: this.state.oberbegriff
    }

    console.log(oberbegriff);

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/oberbegriffe/add', oberbegriff)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))

    this.setState({
      oberbegriff: ''
    })
} 
  

  render()
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Create New Oberbegriff</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>oberbegriff: </label>
            <input  type="text"
                required
                className="form-control"
                value={this.state.oberbegriff}
                onChange={this.onChangeOberbegriff}
                />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create Oberbegriff" className="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  ),
  }
}
```

Comment: And of course the comma before render, as AmitJS94 pointed out.

Comment: And you miss an opening bracket after `render()`: should be `render(){`

Comment: You still don`t have the `axios.post()` function closed. See above (after oberbegriff)

Answer (score 0):

The Code you posted is missing a couple parenthesis. I've commented those in the code.

I'd recommend using prettier plugin in your IDE (VsCode or Brackets) so you don't get too much distracted from coding

### Your Code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class CreateOberbegriff extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeOberbegriff = this.onChangeOberbegriff.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      oberbegriff: ''
    }
  }

  onChangeOberbegriff(e) {
    this.setState({
      oberbegriff: e.target.value
    })
  }

  onSubmit(e) { // onSubmit method is missing the closing parenthesis
    e.preventDefault();

    const oberbegriff = {
      oberbegriff: this.state.oberbegriff
    }

    console.log(oberbegriff);

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/oberbegriffe/add', oberbegriff
      .then(res => console.log(res.data)), // axios.post() function is not closed 

    this.setState({
      oberbegriff: ''
    })
  , // obsolete here

  render() // render method is missing both parenthesis {}
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Create New Oberbegriff</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>oberbegriff: </label>
            <input  type="text"
                required
                className="form-control"
                value={this.state.oberbegriff}
                onChange={this.onChangeOberbegriff}
                />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create Oberbegriff" className="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  ), // oboslete here
  }
}
```

### Code with prettier:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class CreateOberbegriff extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeOberbegriff = this.onChangeOberbegriff.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      oberbegriff: "",
    };
  }

  onChangeOberbegriff(e) {
    this.setState({
      oberbegriff: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const oberbegriff = {
      oberbegriff: this.state.oberbegriff,
    };

    console.log(oberbegriff);

    axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5000/oberbegriffe/add",
      oberbegriff.then((res) => console.log(res.data)),

      this.setState({ oberbegriff: "" })
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Create New Oberbegriff</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <label>oberbegriff: </label>
            <input
              type='text'
              required
              className='form-control'
              value={this.state.oberbegriff}
              onChange={this.onChangeOberbegriff}
            />
          </div>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <input type='submit' value='Create Oberbegriff' className='btn btn-primary' />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at the code I just posted right above your answer? :)